# I'm trying to calculate the average with multiple columns (days and firms) and rows

Tags: excel-formula, average, vlookup

I'm currently trying to calculate the following:

[image: O33639888 question example]

That is, the average daily sales of a firm. The example underneath is small, but in reality I have 280 days and over a 100 firms. I've tried with VLOOKUP(firmname A, (cells), sales) but it obviously only brings back one number. Sum(Vlookup) is also not the best of choice.

Anyone who could point me in the right direction ... SUMIF?

[http://i66.tinypic.com/2wmnrbn.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/koYtV.png)

Comment: would averageifs() work? [Link](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AVERAGEIFS-function-48910c45-1fc0-4389-a028-f7c5c3001690)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming data is located at `B2:C11` and the list of Firms is at `F2:F5` enter this formula in `G3` and copy till last record

```
=AVERAGEIFS($D$3:$D$11,$C$3:$C$11,$F3)
```

[image]